# Меньше чем $lt в агрегации MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, выборка, агрегация

Мне нужно вывести инфу о товарах(в методе прописано какую), но я не понимаю, как в этом же запросе выбрать товары дешевле 100 руб. Пытался через Aggregates.match() передать фильтр, но это работает только если применить до группировки, что мне не нужно. Как это сделать после группировки или в внутри неё?
Метод агрегации в MongoDB:

```
private AggregateIterable<Document> getAggregate() {
    return products.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.lookup("shops", "name", "products", "shopList"),
                    Aggregates.unwind("$shopList"),
                    Aggregates.group("$shopList.name",
                            Accumulators.sum("countProducts", 1),
                            Accumulators.avg("avgPrice", "$price"),
                            Accumulators.min("minPrice", "$price"),
                            Accumulators.max("maxPrice", "$price"))));
}
```

И метод вывода информации:

```
for (Document document: getAggregate()) {
        String name = document.get("_id").toString();
        String info = String.join("\n", "Магазин: " + name,
                "Количество наименований товаров: " + document.get("countProducts"),
                "Средняя цена товара: " + document.get("avgPrice"),
                "Самый дорогой товар: " + document.get("maxPrice"),
                "Самый дешевый товар: " + document.get("minPrice"),
                "Количество товаров дешевле 100 руб.: " + ????;
        System.out.println(info);
    }
```

Метод добавления товара в магазин:

```
public void addProductToShop(String product, String shop) {
    shops.updateOne(getShop(shop), new Document("$addToSet",
            new Document("products", getProduct(product).get("name"))));
    System.out.println("Товар выставлен в магазин");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в агрегатор group сет из цен по каждому магазину -
Accumulators.addToSet("prices", "$price"). В выводе информации получить лист - document.getList("prices", Integer.class). Затем узнать число значений в этом листе, которые меньше 100. Это, конечно, только как альтернатива. Сам новичок в JAVA и мне тоже интересно, как сделать эту задачу в одном pipline.